# Very basic HTML page wont display

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure what is going on here, I made a very basic HTML/CSS page and it just displays an empty page in my browsers.

```
<HTML>
    <head> 
        <style type="text/css">
        #sidebar {float:left; width:20%;}
        .post {float:right; width:79%;}
        #footer {clear:both;}
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <h1>My interesting life</h1> 
        </div> 
        <div id="sidebar"> 
            <h2>Menu</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>Place Link Here</li> 
                <li>Place Link2 Here</li>  
            </ul>  
        </div>
        <div class="post">
            <h2>Yesterday</h2> 
            <p>Today I drank coffee for breakfast.  14 hours later, I went to bed. </p> 
        </div>  
        <div class="post">
            <h2>Yesterday</h2> 
            <p>Ran out of coffee, so had orange juice for breakfast.  It was from concentrate.</p> 
        </div>
        <div id="footer"> 
            <p><small> This is copyright by Monu.  Contact me to negotiate the movie rights. </small></p>  
        </div>
    </body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: try closing the style tag with </style> after the #footer-css format line?

Comment: In the future you may wish to use the [HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to catch simple, but often hard-to-spot, errors like this.

Comment: Or use a text editor with syntax highlighting. When the colors get all wonky, you know you screwed something up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to close your `<style>` tag:

```
<head> 
    <style type="text/css">
        #sidebar {float:left; width:20%;}
        .post {float:right; width:79%;}
        #footer {clear:both;}
    </style>
</head>
```

Answer (score 4):

You did not close the `<style>` tag after the CSS. This makes the browser think the entire rest of the page is CSS. So you need to add a `</style>` tag after the CSS. Hope that helps.

Comment: Correct! Some browsers will correct this for you, but older browsers and IE think the rest of the page is CSS instead of rendering the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you must close the style tag.

To find these errors quickly in the future, consider:

(1) Using HTML and CSS validators such as http://validator.w3.org/
(2) Using Firebug, a Firefox extension, to examine your code for unclosed tags or other oddities.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful advice.  validator.w3.org is pretty cool!

Answer (score 0):

Please close the style tag. `</style>` .........

```
<style type="text/css">
    #sidebar {float:left; width:20%;}
    .post {float:right; width:79%;}
    #footer {clear:both;}
</style>
```

Use some text editor then it help to solve this kind of error....

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the `<style>` tag.  Another thing several developers swear by is adding the `<!DOCTYPE html>` before the normal `<HTML>` tag.`

Comment: this was already an accepted answer, could've accepted that too